# Why the Enhanced MCA gen2 choose to trigger SMI/SCI in firmware first error handling model?

Tags: x86, interrupt, interrupt-handling

In this white paper: https://firmware.intel.com/sites/default/files/resources/A_Tour_beyond_BIOS_Implementing_APEI_with_UEFI_White_Paper.pdf

I see below signaling difference between native MCA model and enhanced MCA firmware first model:

[image]

For Processor CE in the first row:

- the native model use CMC (Corrected Machine Check Interrupt) for signaling. CMCI is reported by respective MCA banks and is handled through the Local APIC's LVT (local vector table).  And all these happen **within** the processor.
- the firmware 1st model,  SMI/SCI are triggered instead of CMC. But as I understand, **SMI/SCI must be triggered through the PCH chipset**, which means going **out of** the processor, all the way to the PCH, and then trigger the SCI/SMI back to the processor.

So why do we need such a long round trip? Or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ACPI Platform Error Interface (APEI) defines two models to handle Machine Errors: *Firmware 1st* and *OS Native*.

The former routes an error condition to the Host firmware first, this way the manufacturer of the board can attempt a recovery and/or log the error information.
The latter steers the error directly to the OS.

These methods are mutually exclusive in a local fashion but not globally, a particular error condition may be Firmware 1st and another may be OS Native.

In the Firmware 1st model, the firmware configures each hardware error source (such as the DRAM controller of an ECC DIMM) to generate a *SMI*.
This invokes the SMM firmware giving the manufacturer an entry point to deal with the error.
Finally, the firmware reports the error to the OS with a SCI or an NMI.

> In the Firmware 1st model, all errors are initially
>   signaled to the host firmware via SMI or other General Purpose Input (GPI) events.
>   Then host
>   firmware analyzes and decides what to do, and at the end of the flow creates a detailed APEI
>   error log with FRU information to OS.
>   Finally, the host firmware will then signal the OS about
>   the existence of the error via SCI, NMI, or other interrupts.

Note that in the first row of the table shows which event is used to signal the error but not how the hardware is really configured.

**Note** I have no experience at all in this topic.

The Processor Correctable Errors (CEs) are all signalled through the Correctable Machine Check Interrupt (CMCI) after a configurable threshold of CE have been detected.
The CMCI has its own entry in the LAPIC LVT (Local Vetor Table)

[image: CMCI interrupt has its own entry in the LAPIC LVT]

I believe this is the only hardware source of Processor CE.
It's theoretically possible to have an external, relative to the core, hardware unit that detects these errors but I have the feeling that the whole picture is leaner than that.

So all Processor CE errors generate a CMCI.
In the Firmware 1st model, the ACPI methods exported by the firmware are coded to configure the CMCI entry to generate an SMI (remember LACPI IVT entries can generate different kinds of interrupts, including SMIs).
In the OS Native model, the ACPI methods don't touch the CMCI.

The SMI is the only way to gives the firmware a way to enter in the flow, it is designed exactly for this purpose and all other interrupts are handled by the OS.
Once the firmware is in control and is done with its checks it can instruct the PCH to generate a SCI.

In the Firmware 1st model the flow has to "exit" the processor anyway because we want to handle the control to the firmware.
To "re-steer it into" the processor the firmware need to generate an interrupt; theoretically, it could resolve the SCI system vector into a CPU local vector but that's unreliable, the better approach is to generate a genuine SCI through the PCH.

I picture the whole thing as

[image: OS Native: CMCI -> Fixed/NMI ; Firmware 1st -> CMCI -> SMI -> IO write -> SCI]

Where the red arrows designate the OS Native flow and the blue ones the Firmware 1st flow.
In the latter case, we opt for a longer trip to give the firmware a chance to act on the error.